# Deleting status post using Ajax POST request

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

how do i delete a single record in database? i tried with Ajax and it didn't work.here is my code,each row has a unique number ID,so i need that to delet it,but i don't know how to get it.

```
echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td>';
    echo '<a href="korisnik.php?id='.$session_poster_id.'">';
    echo '<div class="profile_pic_div" style="margin-top:10px;">';
    echo "<img src='$avatar' style='width:40px;height:40px;'>";
    echo '</div>';
    echo '</a>';
    echo '<div class="timestamp" style="margin-left:50px;margin-top:-43px;font-size:15px;">';
    echo $user['vrijeme'];
    echo '</div>';
    echo '<a href="delete.php?post_id='.$post_id.'">';
    echo '<div class="icon-x" style="margin-left:550px;margin-top:-15px;">';
    echo '</div>';
    echo '</a>';
    echo '<div class="post_div" style="margin-top:30px;">';
    if (strlen($user['post']) > 500) {
        $user['post'] = substr($user['post'], 0, 500);
        $user['post'] = substr($user['post'], 0, strrpos($user['post'], ' ')).'... <a href="story.php?post_id='.$post_id.'">Read More</a>';}
    echo  $user['post'];
    echo '</div>';
    echo '<br>';
    echo '<a href="story.php?id='.$post_id.'">Komentiraj</a>';
    echo '</td>';
    echo '</tr>';
```

Answer (score 0):

DELETE FROM Name_of_your_table
**WHERE Columname = your_value;**

see [w3schools delete query](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_delete.asp)

PS. What is in your delete.php ?

Comment: <?php
//connection omitted

$delete_query=mysqli_query($mysqli,"DELETE FROM posts WHERE post_id = '$post_id'") or die("Failed");
if($delete_query){echo'uspjeh';
header("Location:index.php");}

Comment: Try (in your delete.php on top of your file )  :
$post_id = $_GET['post_id']; 
 
and try to tell what error u get?

Comment: You can also at Limit 1 to your sql query like so : 
DELETE FROM posts WHERE post_id = '$post_id LIMIT 1